# Can numpy.rint to return an Int32?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm doing

```
ret = np.rint(y * 4)
return ret
```

And I want it to return `Int32`. I tried adding `dtype='Int32'`, but it errors saying: `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc rint`

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I tried to search for an answer to no avail

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for any python question. Use version-specific tags at your discretion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ufuncs` have specific rules of what kinds of output they produce given the input.  For `rint` the rules are:

```
In [41]: np.rint.types                                                          
Out[41]: ['e->e', 'f->f', 'd->d', 'g->g', 'F->F', 'D->D', 'G->G', 'O->O']
```

On top of that there are rules about what dtypes can be cast to other dtypes.  We can play with the `out` and the `casting` parameters to produce an integer output, but simply using `astype` after is simpler.

So `rint` normally returns a matching float, even though the values are rounded.

```
In [43]: np.rint(np.linspace(0,10,8))                                           
Out[43]: array([ 0.,  1.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  9., 10.])
```

Simply providing an int `out` doesn't work:

```
In [44]: np.rint(np.linspace(0,10,8),out=np.zeros(8,int))                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-e7f13fa29434> in <module>
----> 1 np.rint(np.linspace(0,10,8),out=np.zeros(8,int))

TypeError: ufunc 'rint' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

We have to give it permission to do a float to int casting:

```
In [45]: np.rint(np.linspace(0,10,8),out=np.zeros(8,int),casting='unsafe')      
Out[45]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  9, 10])
```

The default `casting` for `astype` is 'unsafe'.

```
In [55]: np.rint(np.linspace(0,10,8)).astype(int,casting='safe')                
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: Beware that astype creates a copy. If performance is critical use the first approach.  
`python -m timeit -n 10 -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.normal(size=5000000)' 'np.rint(a).astype("int32")'` 
=> `best of 3: 20.2 msec per loop` 
`python -m timeit -n 10 -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.normal(size=5000000)' 'np.rint(a, out=np.zeros(a.shape, dtype="int32"), casting="unsafe")'` 
=> `best of 3: 10.2 msec per loop` 
`python -m timeit -n 10 -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.normal(size=5000000)' 'np.rint(a, out=a); a.astype("int32")'` 
=> `best of 3: 11.1 msec per loop`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `astype` method ([docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html))

```
ret = np.rint(y * 4).astype(np.int32)
```

Note that `astype` creates a copy, so it may be not the most efficient memory operation (most times you wont care).

sidenote: Why `rint` outputs a `float` dtype array of integers is beyond me.

Comment: You don't think there's any value in preserving the dtype while still rounding?

Comment: I'd say it is more memory efficient to convert to `int` if you know that all your values are integers, it is also default behaviour for pure python `round`. I saw that it is a numpy feature (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11810). Why are the dtypes preserved?

Comment: `int64` and `float64` take up the same space.   `round(1.23, 0)` returns a float :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this will do it:

```
ret = (y * 4)
ret = ret.astype(int)
return ret
```